# Using both OR, AND in an IF-statement - Python

Tags: python

```py
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    if day == 0 or day == 6 and vacation != True:
        return "10.00"
    else: 
        return "off"

print(alarm_clock(0, True))
```

Why does this return "10.00"? In my mind it should return "off". Yes, day is equal to 0, but vacation is True, and the IF-statements first line states that it should only be executed if vacation is not True.

Comment: Python precedence rules: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python `and` binds tighter than `or`. So your statement is equivalent to this:

```
if day == 0 or (day == 6 and vacation != True):
```

To get the correct result you must parenthesize the precedence yourself:

```
if (day == 0 or day == 6) and vacation != True:
```

Comment: THANKS! It works with parenthesis   if (day == 0 or day == 6) and vacation != True:

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use something like `if day in (0, 6) and not vacation:`? It looks pretty more clear to read, IMHO.

Comment: @accdias I would definitely agree with `not vacation`. The `in` statement is arguable but fine either way. However for didactical purposes I only wanted to focus on the immediate problem and solution without bringing in a full code review.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    if (day == 0 or day == 6) and vacation != True:
        return "10.00"
    else: 
        return "off"

print(alarm_clock(0, True))
```